# How to get the position of detected string using mobile vision api

Tags: android

I am using text detection api to scan receipts. I need to get x and y position of the detected string using mobile vision api. 
Can we get the position of the detected string.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What text detection api?  I know a half dozen.  Be more specific.

Comment: It uses ocr to detect the text while scanning(bills)

Comment: I get that.  There's dozens of OCR libraries.  Without knowing which one you used, this is unansweable.

Comment: It's mobile vision  api by google

Comment: It is divided into three types. Text detection , face detection and barcode detection

Comment: Retagged it for you to say that.  The 3 tags mobile, vision, and api didn't quite mean the same thing

Comment: How to get the position of the detected text using mobile vision  api